# How can I solve this question with (<<)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

How can I simplify the top equation in the picture to the lower equation in the picture when the condition t≪v_t/g applies. I dont seem to understand the logic behind it :( Thank you for your help!

Ok guys I just noticed i sent the wrong picture sorry. Here we go again
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUHNx.png)

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to simplify the exponent. $t<<\frac{v_t}{g}$ means $\frac{tg}{v_t} << 1$

You can use the approximation $e^{x} = 1+x $ which is valid for small $x$, this is the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$

Comment: Ok thank you. I want to use this in my paper that I have to give in tomorrow. Do you perhaps have any source that I can relate this too. We still didnt do Taylor expansions.